# Subqueries in Python

Tags: sql, azure-databricks, pyspark

I am trying to use subqueries to run matching against multiple tables and move the unmatched records to new table.

I have written SQL subqueries but the only issue i am facing is the performace, it is taking lot of time to process.

```
create table UnmatchedRecord
(select a.* 
 from HashedValues a 
 where a.Address_Hash not in(select b.Address_Hash 
                             from HashAddress b) 
 and a.Person_Hash not in(select d.Person_Hash 
                          from HashPerson d) 
 and a.HH_Hash not in(select f.HH_Hash 
                      from HashHH f) 
 and a.VehicleRegistration not in(select VehicleRegistration 
                                  from MasterReference) 
 and a.EmailAddress not in (select EmailAddress 
                            from MasterReference) 
 and a.PhoneNumber not in (select PhoneNumber 
                           from MasterReference) 
 and a.NationalInsuranceNo not in (select NationalInsuranceNo 
                                   from MasterReference))
```

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read. (And to write.)

Comment: Thank you for editing the code

Answer (score 1):

You can at least replace four subqueries with one:

```
select HashedValues.*
from HashedValues
where not exists (
    select *
    from MasterReference
    where HashedValues.VehicleRegistration = MasterReference.VehicleRegistration
    or    HashedValues.EmailAddress        = MasterReference.EmailAddress
    or    HashedValues.PhoneNumber         = MasterReference.PhoneNumber
    or    HashedValues.NationalInsuranceNo = MasterReference.NationalInsuranceNo
)
and not exists (
    select *
    from HashAddress
    where HashedValues.Address_Hash = HashAddress.Address_Hash
)
and not exists (
    select *
    from HashPerson
    where HashedValues.Person_Hash = HashPerson.Person_Hash
)
and not exists (
    select *
    from HashHH
    where HashedValues.HH_Hash = HashHH.HH_Hash
)
```

Comment: Will it improve the performance at all. I am running the code in Databricks

Comment: Only one way to find out.